# Where can I learn more about dependencies used in Android

Tags: android, maven, gradle, dependencies

I am a beginning Android.developer I just want to know what are `dependencies`. I know very clearly here in stackoverflow I won't get my full answer(due to its policies) but I am expecting to get a hint to any website where I can learn more about these `dependencies`. Like can I make my own `dependency`?

For example:
Suppose if I have to use features of Facebook in my Android App then I will
write

```
dependencies { 
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
}
```

Now, I know I am importing Facebook SDK, or Facebook dependency and this dependency will give me some classes or interfaces etc to use and connect with Facebook.
**Now my question is can I make my own dependency and how? ** I know the answer is yes, I know there is gradle and maven stuff working under the hood, but I don't know where to start from. Any website or just anything would be very helpful

Comment: "I just want to know what are dependencies" -- they are libraries, available from a structure known as an "artifact repository", to allow tools like Gradle to find and download the libraries as needed. "Now my question is can I make my own dependency" -- yes. "and how?" -- that is much too broad for Stack Overflow. Start by creating a library, whether that is a JAR or an Android library project. You will then need to distribute that library, such as via a Maven-style artifact repository (e.g., JCenter, Maven Central, or your own).

Comment: The Gradle userguide provides a good introduction into dependency managment. Have a look at the chapter "Dependency Management Basics": https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very clear,I can understand you clearly.Now Let me tell you the HOW.
http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en

By the way, I want to tell you that you can solve the problem by your own without any waiting .

[Let me google that for you](http://goo.gl/nLE3nR)

Comment: Your answer is really helpful . Thanks for the websites

Comment: if you found it's helpful then maybe you can accept the answer ,thx!